# How to display a list of Objects in a way other than Gridview in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C#, having done most of my programming in C and C++.

I need to display a list of objects. I can keep them as an ObservableCollection or BindingList or any list type, but I don't want to bind them to a GridView. My code is below:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display this class with a label for Name and a button for Price in small groupboxes, and to update them according to updates from the source list. How should I go about approaching this?

Comment: Hi, @scd, welcome to SO. Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: What I have already done,

I implemented it for a single object. I implemented iNotifyPropertyChanged interface to class Item and got it to update the UI.

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzjmb.png

What I want to do is do this to a list of objects.

Comment: You can use DataRepeater. Put there TextBox control for Name and numericUpDown for Price. Then databind your collection to that controls.

Comment: Use a DataGridView, it supports a column with buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Then you can dynamically build `GroupBox`es and add them to the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) collection. It can be a little difficult to get the hang of building such things dynamically, but it's definitely doable.

This isn't pretty, formatting-wise. But it shows the idea.

```
FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel = ...; // define this in the designer

foreach(var v in items)
{
    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    gb.Text = "Item";

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = v.Name;
    gb.Controls.Add(label);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = v.Price.ToString();
    gb.Controls.Add(btn);

    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(gb);
}
```

Comment: I implemented it this way. Thanx